# Partitions and Equivalence Relations

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have been working on this question for some time and I have looked throughout the forum and internet but have not found any success.

> Let *H* be a subgroup of the group *G* and let the index of *H* in *G* be 2. Show that if the elements *a*, *b* ∈ *G* are not in *H*, then the product *ab* ∈ *H*.

I greatly appreciate any hints as to where to start.

Comment: We have only two cosets, $H$ and "the other one" (which must then be $aH = bH$). If $ab \not\in H$, then we have $ab \in aH$, that is: $ab = ah$ for some $h \in H$. What happens when you multiply this equation on the left by $a^{-1}$?

Comment: I'm sorry Mr. Wheeler but which equation are you referring to? aH=bH?

Comment: Either one, but you may find the $ab = ah$ more accessible.

Comment: I do not see how this is going to show that the product is in H when the elements are not within H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a proof by contradiction. To be clear, we are going to assume the opposite of what we want to prove, and show this leads us to a contradiction.

So here is what is given, that we can rely on:

1. There are only two cosets of $H$. These PARTITION $G$, so it's "one or the other".
2. $a,b$ are not in $H$. This means they BOTH lie in the "other coset".

From 2), we have $aH = bH$. Let's see why:

If $aH = H$, we would have $ah \in H$, say $ah = h'$, for some $h' \in H$. Then $a = ae = a(hh^{-1}) = (ah)h^{-1} = h'h^{-1} \in H$, since $H$ is closed under inverses and multiplication. But this is impossible, since $a \not\in H$. So $aH$ is "the other coset".

Similarly, $bH \neq H$, so $bH$ is *also* the other coset. Since there's only one other coset, it must be $aH$.

So here is where we assume the opposite of what we want to prove: we suppose it is somehow possible that $ab \not\in H$. Since $ab$ is either in $H$, or $aH$ (because $G = H \cup aH$, and $H \cap aH = \emptyset$), if $ab$ is NOT in $H$, it must be in $aH$.

So $ab = ah$, for some element $h \in H$ (we don't even care which one). Thus:

$a^{-1}(ab) = a^{-1}(ah)$, so:

$(a^{-1}a)b = (a^{-1}a)h$ (by associativity), and then:

$b = eb = eh = h$.

But this says $b \in H$, and we know this is not true. This is our contradiction: $b \in H$, and $b \not\in H$ cannot both be true at the same time.

And how did we get to such a sorry state of affairs? We assumed it was possible that $ab \not\in H$. This was our downfall, and to avoid the annihilation of the known universe, we must not make that assumption ever again. But this forces upon us the only OTHER conclusion: $ab \in H$, *quod erat demonstrandum*.